# Adding formated JLabel to JList

Tags: string, for-loop, fonts, jlabel, jlist

yesterday I created a class that list all the available font in a JList and it does what I need...

```
String fonts[] = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames();

JList<Object> list = new JList<Object>(fonts);

scrollpane = new JScrollPane(list);

getContentPane().add(scrollpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

I then started to work on another class that actually creates a JLabel with the name and the format of the font and it gets added to a Panel, this also does what it's supose too.

```
String fonts[] = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
for ( int i = 0; i < fonts.length; i++ )
    {
    JLabel Lname = new JLabel((fonts[i]));
    Font Fname = new Font ((fonts[i]), Font.PLAIN,18);
    Lname.setFont(Fname);
    mainPanel.add(Lname);
    }
```

What I want is to use the JLabel format and add it to the list but for some reason I alwasy loose the format or the content does not display.

Can someone advise how I can join the two together and create a JList with all the formated JLabels?

Many Thanks

Comment: Use `ListCellRenderer`

Comment: @Arvind - many thanks I found a great example and also discover Vector that implements a dynamic array. :-)

Example: [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Howtocreatelistcellrenderer.htm)